# How dismiss ALERT popup while opening a browser

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I open a browser:
'''

```
https://portal-qa1.maytronics.co/#/login/login
```

After successfully logging in (user: Shoval.Ziman@comm-it.com, pass: 123456),
I go to the page I need and a ALERT message appears.
I tried to remove it in many ways, nothing comes out.

1. The switchTo() method - doesn't work.
2. The Robot(), doesn't work two:

   ```
    Robot alertAllow = new Robot();
    alertAllow.mouseMove(280, 160);
    alertAllow.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    alertAllow.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
   ```
3. Also I tried to use the next method:

   ```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2); 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
   ```

   and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
// or
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Usually, after hitting enter or escape most alerts go away.

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work...

Comment: @KattyZa Is the alert an HTML element or is it a Windows pop-up?

Comment: This not really an alert box, this is a chrome browser notification.

Comment: Therefore to switch off this browser notification I created chrome preference map with chrome option, but it doesn't work too. In console got following: WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 98, so returning the closest version found: 95